# Skip page that not found when downloading pdf from multiple page

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, request

i tried to download pdf files from multiple URLs. using this code:

```
import requests

for i in range(1, 40000):
    r = requests.get('http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)

    open('file-risalah'+str(i)+'.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

But apparently, there is a lot of pages that is not found in that 40000 pages, so i got a lot of pdf that is corrupted. How to skip downloading from page that's not found?
i tried using this:

```
import requests
import urllib

try:
    for i in range(2847, 40000):
        r = requests.get('http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)

        open('file-risalah'+str(i)+'.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
except urllib.error.HTTPError:
       print ("pdf not found")
```

but it looks like, it still downloads from pages that are not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

requests gives you the property "ok" to tell you that the page didnt have an error so before opening the file check that like this:

```
import requests

for i in range(1, 40000):
    r = requests.get('http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)
    if r.ok:
        open('file-risalah'+str(i)+'.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should look to the server response. The module `requests` provide the `status_code` for that:

```
import requests
for i in range(1, 40000):
    url = 'http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/' + str(i)
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print(i, url)
        open('file-risalah'+str(i)+'.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the response received from the request before proceeding to download the PDF. If the response has status_code as 200 then you can download the content.

```
import requests

for i in range(1, 40000):
    r = requests.get('http://www.setpp.kemenkeu.go.id/risalah/ambilFileDariDisk/'+str(i), allow_redirects=True, timeout=10)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        open('file-risalah'+str(i)+'.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

status_code 200 means OK. You can read about many [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)